# How to use split in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a string like

`/abc/def/hij/lmn.o // just a raw string for example dont know what would be the content`

I want only `/abc/def/hij` part of string how do I do that.

I tried using `.split()` but did not get any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using javascript

```
var x = '/abc/def/hij/lmn.o';
var y = x.substring(0,x.lastIndexOf("/"));
console.log(y);
```

Answer (score 3):

1. If you want to remove the particular string `/lmn.o`, you can use `replace` function, like this

   ```
   console.log(data.replace("/lmn.o", ""));
   # /abc/def/hij
   ```
2. If you want to remove the last part after the `/`, you can do this

   ```
   console.log("/" + data.split("/").slice(1, -1).join("/"));
   # /abc/def/hij
   ```

Comment: @Pilot I believe the second method in my answer already answers your question.

Comment: thanks ..the 2nd one solves my problem..but I think Its kind of heavy op than REGEX so accepting other as ans

Answer (score 2):

you can do

```
var str = "/abc/def/hij/lmn.o";
var dirname = str.replace(/\/[^/]+$/, "");
```

Alternatively:

```
var dirname = str.split("/").slice(0, -1).join("/");
```

[See the benchmarks](http://jsperf.com/dirname)

[image: dirname benchmark]

Comment: Great..this is what I was probably looking for

Comment: x.substring(0,x.lastIndexOf("/")); My answer seems to be simple. Yet this is the best answer. Keeps me thinking if I got it wrong :D

Comment: @faiz, your answer is completely fine. In fact, in the [benchmark](http://jsperf.com/dirname) I setup, yours performs the best.

Comment: Thanks for genuine comment

Answer (score 0):

```
var s= "/abc/def/hij/lmn.o"
var arr= s.split("/");
```

after this, use

```
arr.pop();
```

to remove the last content of the array which would be `lmn.o`, after which you can use

```
var new_s= arr.join("/");
```

to get `/abc/def/hij`